# Grails File Upload: Tomcat Memory Drain

Tags: performance, grails, file-upload, tomcat6

We're noticing some significant RAM usage while uploading files.  I pretty much expect that but the rate at which the memory is freed seems pretty slow.  And this is causing the whole system to slow down, obviously, when RAM gets too low.

Is there anything that can done, short of adding more RAM, to help improve either the general performance and RAM usage of file uploads or the rate at which objects are GC'd once an upload is complete?  Server settings in Tomcat6?  Something in Grails itself?

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling the file uploads, as described in the Grails manual? That may not be good enough for you if you expect quite some concurrent file uploads (of considerable size) which are very memory consuming.

Seems to me you want to try to let your app keep the uploaded content on disk, not keep it in memory (before it passes the file content to your controller)

Grails uses Commons Fileupload under the hood. In your case it maybe more practical to write a controller that does the handling in a way that is a bit more involved than the regular grails way. Maybe the [streaming](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html) API is what you want, or the [regular way](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) (scroll down to 'Resource cleanup') but with a disk store instead of memory. I think you can just use the code on that page in your controller-action. Commons Fileupload is already on your classpath

Comment: Yea, I'm doing it the "Grails" way and then saving the files to disk.  So in my Grails controller, if I just use the API you linked to, then it will bypass the Grails way?  The only part I guess I don't get is how much has Grails done by the time my controller is executed.

Comment: Also, debugging the request, the file already appears to be being stored on disk, rather than in memory.  So I'm just not clear on how I'm really bypassing Grails by using the FileUpload API directly.  Need some clarification there.  And also, my List of FileItems comes back empty using the code samples provided in the links you provided.

Comment: More info.  I ran across this while searching: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Streaming-file-uploads-td1354299.html

And it would suggest that Grails is already saving the file to disk, not storing it in memory.  It would seem that without a regular old Servlet, I can't vary how it works in the Grails controller all that much.  Which means I also can't implement the cleanup.  What's odd is that these files aren't even that big.  Max 12MB.  Tomcat is running on a 4GB machine and has 2GB dedicated to it.  Tomcat is choking after just a few uploads by 1 person.

Comment: Adding to @HansWesterbeek's answer, here is how you can get started for doing it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892481/stop-grails-from-reading-my-request