# Stop Grails from reading my request

Tags: servlets, grails

I want to create a URL in my Grails application where I want to handle things before Grails read the request body. Specifically, I want to read a file stream and handle it myself before Grails reads it. To do this, I created a custom servlet and mapped it from `web.xml` by following this -

```
grails install-templates
```

Then, created the servlet as `src/java/MyServlet.java` and then added following to `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>        
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload/execute</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, Grails is still reading my request before it reaches my servlet. I suspect this because I am not getting any request body in `MyServlet`

Comment: Have you looked at replacing the `GrailsDispatcherServlet` instance with one of your own that is a subclass of that class?

Comment: That's a large (and brittle) hammer for such a small nail

Comment: Apologies.  I thought it would be easy and simple.

Comment: I just re-read the original question.  I thought he had specifically said he wanted to read the body from a servlet, but he didn't.  That is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Grails has a builtin option to disable processing of Multipart request. Just toggle following setting to true in `Config.groovy` -

```
grails.web.disable.multipart=true
```